# Error generated while transferring application from VC++ 6.0 to Visual Studio 2005

Tags: visual-studio-2005

An error occure saying:

> Unhandled exception at 0xfeeefeee in sgdoc.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xfeeefeee.

While transferring application from VC++ 6.0 to Visual Studio 2005.

Please help me out.

Answer (score 2):

Your program is trying to read from the address 0xFEEEFEEE.

Since this pattern is the marking free'd memory, your program is probably trying to access a pointer inside a struct that has already been deleted.

You will have to let your program crash with a debugger attached and look what is going on before the crash happens.

Answer (score 0):

Without more data I'll venture 2 guesses.

- some memory that was previously initialized with 0 is left uninitialized or is initialized with something else. Check your memory allocation and usage patterns.
- I'm assuming you're using mfc, maybe something changed in the implementation since vc6. Try taking chunks out of your class declarations and see if you can identify the problem like that.

What would help more is the lines around the place where the crash happens, and any related declarations that pertain to that bit of code.